# stable baseline, how can we sample reproducible env value with each episode

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

Iam trying to use DDPG (stable baseline3) to solve a problem.

I would like to know, how can we change the env sampled values with every episode "and it should be reproducible", using stable baseline.

for example, assume we have an env where we harvest energy, we assume that the harvested energy is normally distributed for example, and then in every episode, I will sample DIFFERENT Values of my harvested energy.I would just like to emphasize again, that I would like that the different values of my harvested energy should be reproducible, so I can compare the RL method to other methods. PS: using stable baseline

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: > **My Problem is: how could I change the parameters of my env with every iteration and then ask my agent to learn** ----

I would say, it is not only impossible but also violates the common sense of _reinforcement_ learning.

Comment: I think my question was not properly formulated, its not like I change the parameter of my environment, but for example, assume we have an env where we harvest energy, we assume that the harvested energy is normally distributed for example, and then in every episode, I will sample DIFFERENT Values of my harvested energy. That's now my problem, I would just like to emphasize, that I would like that the different values of my harvested energy should be reproducible, so I can compare the RL method to other methods. PS: using stable baseline.

Comment: I just changed my question again, I dont know if its clear now.